# Nested TypeDict defined as inner class

Tags: python, typeddict

I'm trying to define a "nested" `TypedDict` as a set of inner classes, where `SomeDict` dictionary is supposed to have an `id` field which can be either yet another `TypedDict` or `None`:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class MyClass:

    class SomeIdFieldDict(TypedDict):
        some_nested_field: str

    class SomeDict(TypedDict):
        id: SomeIdFieldDict | None # The error is in this line.
```

The above code gives me the following error: `NameError: name 'SomeIdFieldDict' is not defined`

I've tried to quote the `SomeIdFieldDict`, but now Python type checker treats it as a string:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class MyClass:

    class SomeIdFieldDict(TypedDict):
        some_nested_field: str

    class SomeDict(TypedDict):
        id: "SomeIdFieldDict" | None # The error is in this line.
```

With the above, I'm getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'NoneType'
```

I've also tried referencing to the top-level class, to no avail (getting the same error as above):

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class MyClass:

    class SomeIdFieldDict(TypedDict):
        some_nested_field: str

    class SomeDict(TypedDict):
        id: "MyClass.SomeIdFieldDict" | None # The error is in this line.
```

Yet another approach I've tried taking was to define the `id` type "inline", like so:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class MyClass:

    class SomeDict(TypedDict):
        id: TypedDict("SomeIdFieldDict", {"some_nested_field": str}) | None
```

... but it seems it isn't parsed correctly and the field is being treated as `Any`, the type hints for `id` field show as: `id: Any | None`

Is there any way to be able to define this sort of "nested" `TypeDict` as inner classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `typing.Optional["SomeIdFieldDict"]` instead or, what I would suggest, use [`__future__.annotations`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypedDict


class MyClass:
    class SomeIdFieldDict(TypedDict):
        some_nested_field: str

    class SomeDict(TypedDict):
        id: SomeIdFieldDict | None


def f(x: MyClass.SomeDict) -> None:
    print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f({"id": {"some_nested_field": "a"}})  # works
    f({"foo": "bar"})  # error: Extra key "foo" for TypedDict "SomeDict"
```

This will pass/fail with `mypy` as expected. However, I noticed that PyCharm mistakenly still complains about `Unresolved reference 'SomeIdFieldDict'`. But that is a bug on their end.

Comment: Pylance complains about the type being missing as well, I've created a bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3483. Thanks!